# is there a way to extract smart contract code from bytecode?

Tags: solidity, abi, polygon, bytecode, mainnet

I have deployed the smart contract into polygon mainnet but I do not have the smart contract code now, I only had the smart contract address. I have not 'verify and published ' after deploying the contract.
so right now I only had only smart contract address and its byte code in polygon mainnet.
I need the smart contract code for the same. How to get it?

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to reverse-engineer the bytecode, but it's not going to be fun. You can possibly get some sort of source code, but it will not be anything close to the original, since it has been optimized. It will be just a bunch or difficult-to-read code.

Sorry, I don't really know which tool might be a decent one, or if any of them are.