# What is the easiest way to get an NFT json file?

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, polygon

I have an NFT in my wallet. It's contract address is `0x3cd266509d127d0eac42f4474f57d0526804b44e` in Polygon mainnet.
My NFT ID is 1234.

What is the easiest way to get the NFT json file (`getTokenURI`) based only on these two information (contract address and NFT id)?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're going to need a decompiler, and even then there is no guarantee.

[how to decompile smart contract bytecode?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28877/how-to-decompile-smart-contract-bytecode)

[Lost my deployed contract code. Anyway of viewing this?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38765/lost-my-deployed-contract-code-anyway-of-viewing-this)

[How can you decompile a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract)

[is there a way to extract smart contract code from bytecode?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127669/is-there-a-way-to-extract-smart-contract-code-from-bytecode)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an EIP-721 token. Since the code isn't verified one option is to use a wallet like MyEtherWallet that allows interaction with any contract given its address and the contract's ABI.

You could get the ABI from some of the other EIP-721 contracts from the etherscan page. Calling the standard methods like `tokenUri` shouldn't be a problem.

In that particular address `0x3cd266509d127d0eac42f4474f57d0526804b44e` I got `https://tokens.buildspace.so/assets/CH21b8c9cb-617a-4762-aef4-15147e15513d-25/metadata.json` for tokenId 999.

If that fails you could call the other NFT standard EIP-1155.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to opensea, at the token URL:

https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x3cd266509d127d0eac42f4474f57d0526804b44e/7411

The format is
`https://opensea.io/assets/<NETWORK>/<CONTRACT>/<TOKEN_ID>`

There, you can see the token json link. Just click it and you're done!

[image: opensea token link]